# Get available inventory based on current inventory and new incoming inventory table using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, pivot-table

There are 2 datasets for which I am doing inventory analysis.

Current Inventory

```
Item Id    Date      QUANTITY
Item1   14-Jan-20   100
Item2   14-Jan-20   200
Item3   14-Jan-20   500
```

Incoming Inventory

```
Item Id    Date     QUANTITY
Item1   14-May-20   10
Item1   14-Sep-20   20
Item1   14-Jan-21   30
Item2   14-Sep-20   20
Item2   14-Jan-21   20
Item3   14-Jan-21   100
```

I need to get the result with number of items for a given item for a given date:

```
Item Id    10-Feb-20        03-Oct-20    14-May-22
Item1        100           130         160
Item3        500           500         600
```

I tried this:

```
inventory_df = pd.read_excel('current.xlsx')
new_inventory_df = pd.read_excel('new.xlsx')

df = pd.merge(
    inventory_df,
    new_inventory_df,
    on='Item Number'
)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

df['Inventory Receive'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Inventory Receive'])
df['Inventory Receive'] = df['Inventory Receive'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Hi, I don't see `10-Feb-20`, `03-Oct-20`, or `14-May-22` in `Current Inventory` or `Incoming Inventory`?